# Set different output result location for different tables in aws athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-athena

I have enabled cloudfront logs and want to capture some information through that.

For that I am using aws athena to query cf logs. Which is absolutely working fine for my staging environment as it will store query result in my staging bucket.

For production I have created another table which will query cf logs files from production bucket and that result I want to store it in different s3 bucket( production bucket). But I am not finding any way to have different output query result location. **Is there any way i can set different output result location for different tables**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the QueryResultLocation in S3:

> QueryResultsLocationInS3 is the query result location specified either by workgroup settings or client-side settings.

You can find more detailed information on how to set the location in [Specifying a Query Result Location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html#query-results-specify-location):

> The query result location that Athena uses is determined by a combination of workgroup settings and client-side settings. Client-side settings are based on how you run the query.
>
> - If you run the query using the Athena console, the Query result location entered under Settings in the navigation bar determines the client-side setting.
> - If you run the query using the Athena API, the OutputLocation parameter of the StartQueryExecution action determines the client-side setting.
> - If you use the ODBC or JDBC drivers to run queries, the S3OutputLocation property specified in the connection URL determines the client-side setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the tables with a `CREATE TABLE AS` statement you can set the result location for that specific table in the `WITH` clause. e.g.:

```
 CREATE TABLE table_name
 WITH (
   external_location ='s3://my-bucket/tables/table_name/'
 )
 AS
 SELECT * FROM database.my_table
```

Unfortunately this needs to be an empty location for the query to work. You would need to delete all the files in that location if you wanted to re-run this query, or change the location. See the [Athena documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html) for more details.

Comment: As i cant delete previous files which will be required for reference in future. As i am running this query to create table https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html#create-cloudfront-table